# Is there a built-in method for checking individual list indices in Python

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Python has a built in functionality for checking the validity of entire slices: [`slice.indices`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=slice.indices#slice.indices). Is there something similar that is built-in for individual indices?

Specifically, I have an index, say `a = -2` that I wish to normalize with respect to a 4-element list. Is there a method that is equivalent to the following already built in?

```
def check_index(index, length):
    if index < 0:
        index += length
    if index < 0 or index >= length:
        raise IndexError(...)
```

My end result is to be able to construct a tuple with a single non-`None` element. I am currently using `list.__getitem__` to do the check for me, but it seems a little awkward/overkill:

```
items = [None] * 4
items[a] = 'item'
items = tuple(items)
```

I would like to be able to do

```
a = check_index(a, 4)
items = tuple('item' if i == a else None for i in range(4))
```

Everything in this example is pretty negotiable. The only things that are fixed is that I am getting `a` in a way that can have all of the problems that an arbitrary index can have and that the final result has to be a `tuple`.

I would be more than happy if the solution used numpy and only really applied to numpy arrays instead of Python sequences. Either one would be perfect for the application I have in mind.

Comment: Wait, do you want a tuple or an array? It's hard to tell.

Comment: Have a look here http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579000/

Comment: @user2357112. Final result is a tuple. It will be used to create an index into an array, so I am willing to look at array-only methods for doing the index check.

Comment: @RajanChauhan. I am not sure I understand how that is even remotely relevant.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to go through the intermediate list? It seems perfectly fine to me, and [it's faster](http://ideone.com/7fdvTz).

Comment: @user2357112. I feel like the one liner is cleaner and easier to maintain, but thanks for pointing out the speed difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `range(length)[index]`, in your example `range(4)[-2]`. This properly handles negative and out-of-bounds indices. At least in recent versions of Python, `range()` doesn't literally create a full list so this will have decent performance even for large arguments.

If you have a large number of indices to do this with in parallel, you *might* get better performance doing the calculation with Numpy vectorized arithmetic, but I don't think the technique with `range` will work in that case. You'd have to manually do the calculation using the implementation in your question.

Comment: In terms of what I want: `r = range(4); a = r[a]; items = tuple('item' if i == a else None for i in r)`. Not bad at all. I will wait a little while before selecting just in case.

Comment: @MadPhysicist BTW if you're literally trying to do just that, I wonder if something along the lines of `tuple([None] * a + ['item'] + [None] * (length - a - 1))` would be more efficient... not sure as I haven't tested it, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Not really, since you end up creating a bunch of intermediate lists. I am also creating a couple of these indices, so that the range and `a` both get reused.

Comment: In older versions, you just use `xrange` instead of range.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called `numpy.core.multiarray.normalize_axis_index` which does exactly what I need. It is particularly useful to be because the implementation I had in mind was for `numpy` array indexing:

```
from numpy.core.multiarray import normalize_axis_index

>>> normalize_axis_index(3, 4)
3
>>> normalize_axis_index(-3, 4)
1
>>> normalize_axis_index(-5, 4)
...
numpy.core._internal.AxisError: axis -5 is out of bounds for array of dimension 4
```

The function was added in version 1.13.0. The source for this function is available [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/5a08e209863038b411bc506893093c5a4b8377c9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L4067), and the documentation source is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/5a08e209863038b411bc506893093c5a4b8377c9/numpy/add_newdocs.py#L6739).